# XPages not working since migration from R10 to R11

Tags: xpages, xpinc

A client has migrated from R10 to R11 recently and an XPage has stopped working.  It is embedded in the Notes client as a widget.  When opened on its own via the web, it works ok.

Would anyone have any idea what might help address this issue?

Cheers,

John Collis

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure but it could be related to the fact that the embedded browser was removed from the Notes Client because they didn't want to have to keep it up to date.

We are using 'embedded experiences' which displayed xpages in place of the email body, from 9.0.1 FP9 this was no longer possible due to the embedded browser being removed.

I would assume that the 'widget' also uses the embedded browser to display a webpage using a URL (in this case an xpages url)

Here is the description from 'what's new'

> Starting with V9.0.1 FP9, the Embedded Browser is no longer available on the client platform, and cannot be used in clients or plug-ins. As a result, the "Web Browser" option no longer displays in the Notes client Preference menu; the user's default external browser is used instead.

If your xpage widget was working with V10 then I am not sure if this is the cause of your problem, because it shouldn't have been working for V10 if it was related to the embedded browser.